# Ligatures for fi, fl, ffl do not work for Times New Roman (XeLaTeX)

Tags: ligatures, times

When I compile the code below with XeLaTeX (using TeXworks), ligatures for Times New Roman do not show. Instead, I just get singular characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.05]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Ligatures: fi fl ffl

\end{document}
```

I have tried `Ligatures={Common}` and `Ligatures={Common, TeX}` instead of `Ligatures=TeX` (found in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226437/font-search-handwritten-font/226516#226516) answer), but there is no difference. I've checked the font map for Times New Roman (v.6.85) and the Unicode characters FB01 and FB02 are present with the expected ligatures.

However, when I do not specify the font, the above (thus set in Computer Modern) **does** have  ligatures.

It is not terribly important for me to use Times New Roman, but it has IPA characters (which I need for my linguistics thesis), and old style numerals and small caps (which I like).

Is there a way for me to get Times New Roman to show these ligatures?

Comment: Imho they are not activated and can't be accessed by the ligature option. But if the glyphs are there then it should be possible to create a mapping file to use them. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227341/how-to-keep-both-mapping-arabicdigits-and-ligatures-tex-in-this-mwe/227346#227346

Comment: [Linux Libertine O](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=87&L=1) is a good alternative with old style numerals, small caps (even bold small caps), full IPA coverage (except for the labiodental flap [ⱱ]), and decent diacritic placement. It has the ligatures you want, plus several more, and they work fine with XeLaTeX, even decomposing correctly in the PDF for searching and copy-and-pasting. I use `fontspec` to access the lining numerals in glosses and example numbers and the old style numerals elsewhere in my thesis.

Comment: That is a beautiful-looking font, Jason Zentz. I might just try it. Regarding your last sentence: how did you make fontspec use lining numerals in glosses and examples but not elsewhere? I looked at the documention but I'm still unsure.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about the author-tag function. How did you set up `fontspec` the way you described @JasonZentz ?

Comment: @P.deRijke, I can't really fit my code for that in a comment, and I think it would be better suited as an answer to a follow-up question, anyway. So feel free to ask that in a new question and I'd be happy to answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prepare a new map file, I called it `rijke.map`

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

; additions for f ligatures
;U+0066 U+0066 U+0069 <> U+FB03 ; LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FFI
;U+0066 U+0066 U+006C <> U+FB04 ; LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FFL
;U+0066 U+0066        <> U+FB00 ; LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF
U+0066 U+0069        <> U+FB01 ; LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI
U+0066 U+006C        <> U+FB02 ; LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FL
```

The basis is the standard `tex-text.map` file found in TeX Live. The “ff” ligatures are commented out, because my copy of Times New Roman doesn't support them.

Now compile it

```
teckit_compile rijke.map
```

This will produce a `rijke.tec` file; if you keep it along your document, the input

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=rijke,Scale=1.05]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Ligatures: ff ffi ffl fi fl 

\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. I did not know this was possible.

Comment: It worked for me. However, my copy of Times New Roman also does not support "ff" ligatures. Any idea where and how to get one that does?

Comment: @FrankEjbyPoulsen Try TeX Gyre Termes

Comment: How do I create a .map file?

Comment: @ahorn I usually copy `tex-text.map` in a working directory, with a different name, and modify it like in the example above. The base file is found in the TeX tree; in TeX Live it is at `/usr/local/texlive/<year>/texmf-dist/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/base/tex-text.map` (use the proper value for `<year>`, such as `2016`).

Comment: @egreg my computer doesn't know which program to use to open the .map file.

Comment: I will just use Notepad.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10 1803, it seems Times New Roman has been updated to version 7.00, and some (more) ligatures have been added (but into `dlig` lookup, rather than the more widely-used `liga`). We can then use `fontspec` to turn on this feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\verb|Default:                  |
fi fj fl ff ffi ffj ffl Th

\verb|Ligatures=Discretionary:  |
{\fontspec{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=Discretionary] % or `Ligatures=Rare`
fi fj fl ff ffi ffj ffl Th}
\end{document}
```

[image]