# Remapping German sharp s (Eszett)

Tags: german, mapping

I assume mine is a general problem with remapping, but what I want to do
is to use, with Linux Libertine (and XeLaTeX), the round (ligature ss)
form of German sharp s (E04C) instead of the standard form (00DF).

I thought this could be done by adding

```
U+00DF <> U+E04C
```

to my tex-text.map.

This does not seem to work however. Compiling

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Lessingstraße
\end{document}
```

with XeLaTeX still gives me 00DF in ``Lessingstra_ß_e''.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance,

Rainer

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Would you be open to using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX? If so, you could use an OpenType feature file to perform the substitution from `ß` (00DF) to `ß` (E04C).

Comment: How exactly did you add the mapping? Did you call teckit afterwards? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230118/ligatures-for-fi-fl-ffl-do-not-work-for-times-new-roman-xelatex/230140#230140

Comment: @Mico: XeLaTeX supports OpenType as well. The problem is that there is no OpenType feature for this glyph for some reason – except for *access all alternates,* which is not natively supported by Fontspec, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

If using LuaLaTeX is an option for you, you could achieve your objective by (a) defining a Lua function that replaces all instances of `ß` with `\char"E04C` and (b) adding this function to the `process_input_buffer` callback. As its name indicates, this callback processes the input buffer *before* TeX does any processing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{luacode}
function replace_eszett( line )
    return string.gsub( line, 'ß', '\\char"E04C ' )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer",  
    replace_eszett, "replace_eszett" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
Lessingstraße \emph{Lessingstraße}
\end{document}
```

For completeness, here's what the output of the preceding example looks like *without* the lua-based code:

[image]

Comment: I know this is not a tex question, but I would be curious to know what the problem with one or the other is and where and when it would be preferable to use the former or the latter. I see that they are different, but is there any reason why one should be "right" and the other one "wrong"?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do achieve the desired output as follows using `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xltxtra, newunicodechar}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\newunicodechar{ß}{^^^^e04c}
\begin{document}
Lessingstraße
\end{document}
```

In the fourth line, you can also use `\newunicodechar{ß}{}`, where the second argument is the Unicode character U+E04C.

Finally, you can use the way described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255327/28608) to directly access a font’s glyphs:

```
\newunicodechar{ß}{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "germandbls.alt"\relax}
```

This way, you do not not employ Unicode’s Private-Use Area at any point, which makes the mapping more robust to changes to the font’s encoding, also works for characters that are not assinged to a Unicode code point in the first place and also works with other fonts using the same naming convention.

Comment: Maybe you prefer `\newunicodechar{ß}{^^^^e04c}` that's more readable. Avoid loading `xltxtra`, just `fontspec` is needed.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the hint. I used `xltxtra`, because the question used it and it does not matter for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:  I needed to compile the relevant .map-file:

teckit_compile tex-text.map -o tex-text.tec

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to modify a standard mapping file; create a new one, with a different name.