# Ligatures in Times New Roman with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, ligatures

I would like to display ligatures in a text set with Times New Roman, using LuaLaTeX to compile. I have tried `\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common]{Times New Roman}` as well as `Ligatures=TeX`. Both seem to be ignored. The ligature glyphs are installed on my system.

In an older answer I saw that I can manually map the ligatures ([Ligatures for fi, fl, ffl do not work for Times New Roman (XeLaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230118/ligatures-for-fi-fl-ffl-do-not-work-for-times-new-roman-xelatex)). However, I was wondering if this has become simpler in 2020.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

office fit fluent

o{f}{f}ice {f}it {f}luent %to display text without ligatures

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some unknown reason times puts these ligatures under `dlig`. So use the `Rare` option.
Braces don't suppress ligatures, use `\/`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=Rare]

\begin{document}

office fit fluent ---

o{f}{f}ice {f}it {f}luent %doesn't work to display text without ligatures

of\/fice f\/it f\/luent %to display text without ligatures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did it, thanks! How do I find out which option I need to use for which font?

Comment: I used `otfinfo --script=latn -f times.tff`  to check the features and then guessed.

Comment: I'll try that, although I might not be as lucky in guessing :)

Comment: After 10 or 20 wrong guesses you will get the hang on it. It is mostly training. (The fontspec docu contains some explanations about the features).

Comment: I note also that the [TeX Gyre Termes](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre-termes?lang=en) version of Times New Roman does these ligatures correctly without any `[Ligatures=...]` option.

Comment: There's another `\/` missing: `of\/f\/ice` :)